# How to load configurations at Vue JS app start

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I want to load some configuration from an API call before any page load happens. For this I added my api call function in main.js but it returns promise and page get loaded before my global api completes. I want to load the global configuration first as my backend services URLs will keep on changing.

my main.js

```js
import globalConfigLogic from '../appStarter/globalConfig-logic';
import globalConfigDetails from '../appStarter/app-starter.js';


// API Wrapper - Global Mixin
Vue.mixin(apiWrapper)
Vue.use(VeeValidate);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;


 globalConfigLogic.getGlobalConfiguration(
   globalConfigDetails.globalConfigHost,
   globalConfigDetails.globalConfigHostPort,
   globalConfigDetails.globalConfigKeys
 );
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

The functions is just making an API call and converting the result in hashmap and giving it back.

Answer (score 0):

If loading your configuration returns a promise, simply put the creation of the Vue instance in the `.then() {}` code.